# How to add 'sequence'column to make a PK in table(Oracle and MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a question about adding a sequence column in the table I have.

The table looks like this.

-SQL(MySQL) :

```
SELECT A.CI_NUM, 
       A.DL_DT, 
       A.DL_PRC
FROM (SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210701' AS DL_DT, 700 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL
      SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210701' AS DL_DT, 500 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210701' AS DL_DT, 600 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210805' AS DL_DT, 600 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210805' AS DL_DT, 350 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210805' AS DL_DT, 400 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210510' AS DL_DT, 300 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210510' AS DL_DT, 350 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210510' AS DL_DT, 200 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210603' AS DL_DT, 700 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210603' AS DL_DT, 650 AS DL_PRC
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210603' AS DL_DT, 400 AS DL_PRC
) A;
```

-result :

[image]

In this table, I want to add a sequence column to make a PK for this table.

The table that I want looks like this.

[image]

I want to add SQ column using ALTER TABLE and want to apply this in Oracle table and MySQL table.

If you answer this question, I really appreciate that.

Comment: What is the condition and order of the sequence? There's no consistency in your order. I was assuming that the order is by `DL_PRC` descending however, it's clearly not. I mean, look at the first 3 in your expected result, the order of `DL_PRC` is `700, 500, 600`, how do you determine the `SQ` assignment? Also, what is MySQL version?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have SEQUENCE, it uses the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute of a column.

Comment: In MySQL you can only have an auto increment secondary column with the MYISAM engine, not InnoDB. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I want to put just numbers starting from 1 by 'CI_NUM'col and 'DL_DT'col in 'SQ'col. In short, 'SQ'col doesn't have any relation with 'DL_PRC'col.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can get the SQ value using window function, please see sql bellow:

```
SELECT A.CI_NUM, 
   A.DL_DT,
   row_number() over (partition by A.CI_NUM,A.DL_DT) AS SQ,
   A.DL_PRC
FROM (SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210701' AS DL_DT, 700 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210701' AS DL_DT, 500 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210701' AS DL_DT, 600 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210805' AS DL_DT, 600 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210805' AS DL_DT, 350 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '1000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210805' AS DL_DT, 400 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210510' AS DL_DT, 300 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210510' AS DL_DT, 350 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210510' AS DL_DT, 200 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210603' AS DL_DT, 700 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210603' AS DL_DT, 650 AS DL_PRC
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2000000001' AS CI_NUM, '20210603' AS DL_DT, 400 AS DL_PRC
) A;
```

If you have that table in your database you first need to add SQ column with some default value then use the sql above and write a cte that will be used for updating the original table, then you can add a composite PK on the table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTble
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY(CI_NUM,DL_DT,SQ);
```

going forward you also will need trigger or somehow to get the next value in every group(CI_NUM,DL_DT) and use that as value for SQ in your insert statement.

Hope I give you an idea how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 12c and above you may use `generated ... as identity` to create an autoincrement column. Then make it a primary key, because Oracle throws an error if you do this in single operation.

> ```
> create table t(val int)
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values(0)
> ```

> ```
> alter table t add (
>   id int generated by default as identity
> )
> ```

> ```
> alter table t add (
>   constraint t_pk primary key (id)
> )
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> VAL | ID
> --: | -:
>   0 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc5889acf8a760e8c6b9cc01c2b0be12)*

For MySQL it can be done in one step, because it forces you to declare it as a pk:

> ```
> create table t(val int)
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values(0)
> ```

> ```
> alter table t add (
>   id int auto_increment primary key
> )
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> val | id
> --: | -:
>   0 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=522cb618a5f7080bf597f7e6de04a636)*

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but I want to make PK using 'CI_NUM'col, 'DL_DT'col, and 'SQ'col. I think PK consists of only one col('id'col) in your answer. How can I make PK have those three columns adding 'SQ'col(I just want to make 'SQ'col have numbers starting from 1 by 'CI_NUM'col and 'DL_DT'col)?

Comment: @WooseokChoi 1) As was said in the comments to the question, MySQL has no sequences. 2) sequence cannot be declared for every new value of other columns. So you either have to generate sequence numbers on-the-fly and retrieve maximum number by other columns of the key on each insert (which will also require `..for update` addition to avoid concurrent insert of the same generated `id`) or have general sequence (auto increment column) as a single column PK.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
SELECT CI_NUM, DL_DT,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CI_NUM, DL_DT) AS SQ, /*generate SQ*/
       DL_PRC
  FROM ( 
      ...your subquery..
   ) A;
```

If you're on version that supports `ROW_NUMBER()` function, then this solution should suffice. But if you're on an older version, try this instead:

```
SELECT CI_NUM, DL_DT,
       CASE WHEN @cn = CI_NUM AND @dd = DL_DT THEN @rownum := @rownum+1
            ELSE @rownum := 1 END AS SQ,
       DL_PRC,
       @cn := CI_NUM,
       @dd := DL_DT
  FROM (SELECT @cn := NULL, @dd:= NULL, @rownum := 1) v
  CROSS JOIN ( 
      ...your subquery..
   ) A
;
```

Longer query, a little harder to understand but with the same idea of using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d6eca716667d8bd3c981c53294b0618)